# Update query is giving weird error "CfPlnUt_Aemk5Mr77-AevA2"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ado.net

I am trying to update a column in a temp table, based on some condition but getting  a weird error.

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CfPlnUt_Aemk5Mr77-AevA2' to data type int.
```

This error is for **WelcomeEmailStatus** column.
Below is my update query.

```
UPDATE G  
    SET G.GroupNameAnchor = (Case When ChatGroupType IS NULL OR ChatGroupType = 3 
                            Then dbo.GetHRChatTitle(G.UserChatGroupId) Else G.GroupNameAnchor End)
    ,
    G.WelcomeEmailStatus = (Case When G.MessageId IS NOT NULL AND Exists (Select top 1 E.Status From EmailStatus E Where E.MessageId = G.MessageId)
                                Then (Select top 1 E.Status From EmailStatus E Where E.MessageId = G.MessageId) Else 0 End)
    FROM #OnlineUsersOrGroups G;
```

Even below query is also giving same error.

```
UPDATE G  
    SET G.GroupNameAnchor = (Case When ChatGroupType IS NULL OR ChatGroupType = 3 
                            Then dbo.GetHRChatTitle(G.UserChatGroupId) Else G.GroupNameAnchor End)
    ,
    G.WelcomeEmailStatus = (Case When G.MessageId IS NOT NULL AND Exists (Select top 1 E.Status From EmailStatus E Where E.MessageId = G.MessageId)
                                Then 1 Else 0 End)
    FROM #OnlineUsersOrGroups G;
```

Below is table schema

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OnlineUsersOrGroups') IS NOT NULL  
        DROP TABLE #OnlineUsersOrGroups;  
    Create Table #OnlineUsersOrGroups(row int,
                UserId int,
                OnlineAt DateTime,
                UserRank int,
                UserStatus int,
                LastLoginAt DateTime,
                GroupOrUsername Varchar(Max),
                UserInstallId Varchar(1000),
                Picture Varchar(1000),
                DepartmentId int,
                DepartmentName Varchar(1000),
                LastMessage Varchar(Max),
                MessageId int,
                MessageAt DateTime,
                ReceiverIds Varchar(Max),
                IsRead bit,
                chatgroupid Varchar(Max),
                TaskId bigint,
                TaskMultilevelListId int,
                UserChatGroupId int,
                ChatGroupType int,
                ChatGroupMemberImages Varchar(Max),
                GroupNameAnchor Varchar(Max),
                UnreadCount int,
                TotalAutoEntries int,
                WelcomeEmailStatus int not null default(0))
```

Comment: You'r trying to convert the string `'CfPlnUt_Aemk5Mr77-AevA2'` to int which is not possible. I think your issue is here `dbo.GetHRChatTitle(G.UserChatGroupId)` which propably return the string instead of int.

Comment: What's the schema for the `EmailStatus` table?

Comment: @Sami: No, that part is perfect, that column is of varchar type. problem is in WelcomeEmailStatus only. Staus column is of int type in EmailStatus table.

Comment: @Sami I updated the question, pls check.

Comment: @Diado I updated the question, pls check.

Comment: What are the data types of the `EmailStatus.Status` and `EmailStatus.MessageId` columns? (based on your edit, particularly the MessageId column)

Comment: both int, even if i replace that complete part with value 1, it still gives same issue.

Comment: @Diado: you pointed out the right thing, I found the issue now. EmailStatus.MessageId is of varchar type which is giving issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it's clearly wrong. Good to know you've found the problem. @Diado, you might want to post an answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Have posted an answering summarizing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that your query is trying to compare a column of type `INT` to a value which is not an `INT`, in this case the `VARCHAR` `'CfPlnUt_Aemk5Mr77-AevA2'`

Given that hard-coding the setting of the `WelcomeEmailStatus` column to 1 doesn't solve it, the error can only be caused by the comparison `E.MessageId = G.MessageId` in your `EXISTS` clause.

Based on your comments, the `EmailStatus.MessageId` is an `INT`, but you are comparing it to `#OnlineUsersOrGroups.MessageId` which is a `VARCHAR`.